# What's the difference between IP forwarding via /etc/sysctl.conf and /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ipv4

I've only used `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to enable/disable IP forwarding so far.
However, I recently came across [a video](https://youtu.be/NAdJojxENEU?t=1920) where the author uses `/etc/sysctl.conf` to enable IP forwarding. Did he do that so that the modification survives reboots?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was true - Writing to sysctl.conf allows for permanent changes. Source - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/making-changes-to-proc-filesystem-permanently/